# Show y Hide en js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Hola me estan pidiendo algo

tengo este codigo:

```
$("#divNeeds").hide(2000);
$("#divNeeds").hide("slow");
$("#divHome").show();
```

Pero esto aparece de abajo hacia arriba, pero me estan pidiendo que aparezca de derecha a izquierda y no encuentro que atributo cambiarle. sabes si por js eso se puede hacer?

[image: Img1] 
[image: Img2]
[image: Img3]

Qui pueden ver como va subiendo el div

Gracias por la colaboración

Comment: Por favor, crea un [mcve] para que podamos ver el problema en la propia pregunta en lugar de imágenes que son difíciles de entender  (dices que quieres que un elemento aparezca, pero la secuencia de imágenes es un elemento desapareciendo). Además, el problema no termina de estar del todo claro, trata de añadir una descripción más detallada de lo que quieres obtener. Lee [ask] para más información y recomendaciones.

Comment: Como que no se entendió? es un div cualquiera, al cual le aplico el js que puse en la pregunta. Yo pienso que se entiende que estoy escondiendo el divNeeds y que se muestra el divHome, y para mi esta claro que el div aparece de abajo hacia arriba y necesitaba que se mostrara de izquierda a derecha. Y las imagenes estan en ese orden para que vean como va subiendo el ddiv para ocultar el otro. 

Igual gracias por la sugerencia en la próxima pongo el código de la vista, solo que no pensé que fuera necesario para este ejemplo en concreto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acuerdo a el usuario Italy de SO en inglés:

aquí su perfil: [perfil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1947677/itay)

aquí su respuesta: [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18887449/hide-show-from-left?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

este es un ejemplo que puedes usar y adaptar a tus necesidades, si accedes al enlace del autor original de la respuesta notaras un enlace aún válido a jsfiddle con el ejemplo funcional:

este ejemplo es el HTML

```
<a href="#" id="button" class="button_style">Hide content</a>
<div id="hidden_content">Content</div>
```

con ayuda de jquery 1.8 o superior

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#button").toggle(function() {
        $(this).text('Show Content');
    }, function() {
        $(this).text('Hide Content');
    }).click(function(){
        $("#hidden_content").animate({width: 'toggle'}, "slow");
    });
});
```

Para ayudar al efecto que buscas, se hace también desde CSS así

```
a {
    display: block;
}
#hidden_content {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: @Alvaro Montoro es así válido referenciar la respuesta de otro usuario o estoy mal a como entendí en la guía de como responder

Comment: Sí, con eso basta para referenciar la publicación de otro usuario (incluso te podrías ahorrar el enlace a su perfil si quieres). Para más información sobre cómo referenciar material de otros usuarios, lee [¿Cómo referenciar material escrito por otra persona?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/referencing) en el centro de ayuda.

Comment: ¿Cómo debería adaptarse el código de esa respuesta para que funcione con esta pregunta en concreto?